# TRYING TO CREATE SIMPLE TO-DO LIST WITH LOOPS

Tags: javascript

[image]

**What I need**

1. Display ******** when I type list.

I'm doing a simple to-do-list using loops(if, while) but according to my code when I type list it should show me **********. But it doesn't display anything, but when I type quit it displays the both while and if condition. please help me to sort out the problem.

**My-code**

```js
let input = prompt('QUESTION');

while (input !== 'QUIT' && input !== 'q') {
  if (input === 'LIST') {
    console.log('**********');
  }

  input = prompt('QUESTION')
}

console.log('OK GOOGLE')
```

Comment: It works for me. When I type `LIST` the console shows `*******`

Comment: It doesn't work that way in the stack snippet because fake console is in the DOM, and doesn't render until the script returns. But you can see it in the real browser console.

Comment: What browser are you using? It works in Chrome.

Comment: Because promt/alert is blocking code, and takes precedence over console.log

Comment: @Barmar I too use chrome but it doesn't show me the output rather I displays when I type quit.

Comment: I don't know why it's working different for you, but there's nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this bro

```js
let input = prompt('QUESTIONq');

if(input === "q" || input === "QUIT" ){
  console.log("OK GOOGLE");
}else if(input === "LIST"){
    console.log('**********');
}
```

Comment: bro is not the term to be used here while adding answers, and also while adding answers make sure to add detailed explaination of what your code is doing, and how it solves the actual problem.